# Django form field size

Tags: python, django

Right now my filter form text field size is very large I'm trying to make the form textfield size smaller.How can I make them smaller I tried giving an id to my form and tried changing the size using css , but it didn't work.

```
filter.py

import django_filters
from django_filters import DateFilter

from .models import Order

class OrderFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    start_date = DateFilter(field_name="date_created", lookup_expr='gte')
    end_date = DateFilter(field_name="date_created", lookup_expr='lte',)
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['status']
```

```
order_list.html

<form class="filter-form" method="GET" action="">

  {{myFilter.form}}


<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>


</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to define the widget:

```
start_date = DateFilter(field_name="date_created",lookup_expr='gte',widget=DateInput(attrs={'style':'width:150px; height:30px'}))
```